# How to iterate array inside object without loop using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to iterate array inside object value without loop.but I got undefined value output.

**sample.js**

```
data = [{'product_name':"hari"},{'product_name':"main"}]
console.log(data.product_name)
```

**Expected output**

```
hari
main
```

**I got output**

```
undefined
```

Comment: what means "*without loop*"?

Comment: `console.log(data[0].product_name, data[1].product_name);`? Is there any reason for avoid looping anyway?

Comment: `data` is an array, so: `data[0].product_name`.

Comment: use map  function like this: data.map(res=>res.product_name)

Comment: You can't iterate without a loop. Even using `Array.forEach` performs a loop, it's just handled by JS instead of you writing the loop yourself. If you're only ever going to have two values, you can just hard-code the indexes 0 and 1; if there could be different numbers of entries, then you *need* to loop. Why are you trying to do this without loops?

Answer (score 1):

### Why it failed

The "data" is an array in your definition, thus this will be undefined:

```
data.product_name // undefined
```

Whereas your data is here:

```
data[0].product_name // hari
data[1].product_name // main
```

### How to iterate and log

```
// a) Simple "for" loop
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
  console.log(data[i].product_name);
}

// b) Array.forEach
data.forEach((product) => {
   console.log(product.product_name);
})
```

There are many different ways to iterate over arrays.
Consider reading this for [differences between for/forEach/for in loops](https://codeburst.io/javascript-the-difference-between-foreach-and-for-in-992db038e4c2)
and **going through JS basics and tutorials**.

### Alternatively, if the target is "avoiding the loop"

You could store the data in a (nested) array, like this:

```
data = {};
data.product_names = ['hari', 'main'];

console.log(data.product_names); // Outputs ['hari', 'main']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
data = [{'product_name':"hari"},{'product_name':"main"}]
result = data.map(res=>res.product_name)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is

```
data.forEach((obj) => {
   console.log(obj.product_name)
})
```

Comment: "*without loop*"

Comment: You should try this Object.values(data)